# How to check if any set of vectors generate linear space

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to show if any set of vectors generate a space. I know that there must be at least 3 vectors to generate $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ space etc, and they have to be linear independent, so in that case if we show that the vectors from set are independent, then  they generate our space. But let's say we have 5 vectors in our 
 set. How to check if this set of 5 vectors generate $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ space and if they do, then which vectors of our set create the base of $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ ? I know that simply we have to check which one are independent. But can we do that in one "step", not by checking if any set of 3 vectors are independent?

Comment: Do you need an analytical answer or a numerical one such as a MATLAB code?

Comment: How would you interpret "our space" as a vector space, in particular $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the five vectors in the rows of a matrix, then row-reduce the matrix using the Gauss algorithm (without ever swapping rows if you want to keep track to which vectors they correspond). The non-zero rows at the end of the procedure still generate the same subspace.

The general principle I'm using here is that row operations preserve the row space.